# Send messages with https://webchat.botframework.com/

Tags: azure, botframework, web-chat

I'm trying to send messages following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-send-and-receive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#send-message) guide, but i'm getting 403.
The bot is deployed on Azure using Web App Bot template.

**I got the bearer token**

```
curl -X POST \
  https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: ea607e32-4939-4005-85f4-440bc71d6e12' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=655fde6d-0086-4b7c-b82c-8033b05555e5&client_secret=C*bd%3B%7D%5Ed1%3F7_(D%5Dq%5E%2B%2Bm6c%5E%5BQ-%7D&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default&undefined='
```

**Send message with auth**

```
curl -X POST \
  https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/conversations/26573ac9cd7c4242aaa3c9692248b11a/activities \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ii1zeE1KTUxDSURXTVRQdlp5SjZ0eC1DRHh3MCIsImtpZCI6Ii1zeE1KTUxDSURXTVRQdlp5SjZ0eC1DRHh3MCJ9.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.B4837ahaYuc00_dU8v-RyuC0CC0NXXKSGaNFyj5VcjkGsMUfKRBfXtDfebv0mMbDz7Vaw_VSmO4Y-WSn_LOrYv6qqB1-vGhD6zf3DkZ3SUnSUVkNmTS93Vc2N18C6pvAm129P2-YYlCJu-bQJtX-ZKXFjcJ2oQ70P-X3A-zFrVj1rSzd6pyRqRLJJw58ZnaAUosBs7KgEzDoRCRn61lcrDqIny-BoWrlGsTPMUWl2hAsZnj-0-QR0CE1oxTTfkRYElZua1zwsKf6-VaOxvQNhtkHemzqpo5ctUyQMmlkHEVyUCXhUPzPNYdgPyF87pLJq7fhimgRAe5YAjJMlbRANA' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: f19c7788-3933-4b4a-9ce6-ebfcc953903f' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
        "id": "NotificationApi",
        "name": "Notification"
    },
    "text": "Haircut on Saturday"
}'
```

The serviceUrl and conversation I got from session.message.address

Then, the response code is 403- Forbiden.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the mistake here is that you're attempting to authenticate the WebChat channel with an OAuth based bearer token rather than using token based authentication. OAuth token acquisition happens *over* the channel once it's connection is established.

[This blog post](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/09/01/using-webchat-with-azure-bot-services-authentication/) does a pretty good job explaining the difference between the two and walking through the various steps of configuring an DirectLine channel (which supports more advanced scenario for acquiring tokens), fetching a token from it for the WebChat to use and then, later, performing the OAuth token exchange via the Bot Framework Service.

Comment: Thanks, Drew Marsh. The scenario a I wanted to test was: send messages via WebChat API. Reading the blog you've linked I understood that I could do that without Direct Line.  I'm gonna make this in the bot logic;
        carteiroAPI.getNotifications()
            .then((result) => {
                const list = result.data.result
                list.forEach((message) => {
                    var msg = new builder.Message().address(message.address);
                    msg.text(message.message);
                    bot.send(msg);
                });